# Improve diff view readability in suggested Q/A edits and proposed documentation changes

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, documentation-proposals, diff

Looking at "side-by-side (markdown)" diff views is a bit of a headache, when it comes down to an entire Q/A/topic/example being rewritten.

Take [this proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/85540), for example:

> [image]

Since it's completely rewritten, there's no point in showing the actual diff, I just want to compare the 2 sides globally. Removing the highlighting actually makes that easier:

> [image]

Or maybe only remove the <strike>strike</strike>, to make the left side that much more readable:

> [image]

For inline diff, the highlighting makes sense, even though the strike makes it harder to read.

I'd like to request a option to toggle whether or not to show the red / green highlights, or just to remove the strike.
It'd improve readability of the diff views.

Comment: I assume that the purpose of the strike is to make this feature accessible for colorblind users, who could not otherwise distinguish between the poorly-chosen red and green? Because, as a non-color-blind individual, I never use striked-through text in my diff utilities because it makes it too hard to read.

Comment: Possibly, but those users should still be able to identify which parts of the text are marked, when the strike is removed, not?

Comment: @Cerbrus I would hope that we're using colors that are easily distinguished by the colorblind. Otherwise it would not be easy to tell what's going on when it's the inline view. But I agree strike through makes it hard to read for everyone.

Comment: I think the strikethrough makes it easier to read.

Comment: @developerwjk: Are you serious? How does a strikethrough make anything easier to read?

Comment: Its more semantic.

Comment: Semantic doesn't necessarily mean "Easy to read".